# jQuery send multiple values to the ajax in a order way

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have my markup like this

```
<form action="">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>file name</td>
        <td> file language</td>
        <td class="checkboxes">
            <input type="checkbox" name="finance_received_document[]" class="received-file-project" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="source_language" value="English"><input type="hidden" name="target_language" value="German">
            <input type="hidden" name="title" value="test_file">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_group_name" value="Article Rewrite_Test"></td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>file name</td>
        <td> file language</td>
        <td class="checkboxes">
            <input type="checkbox" name="finance_received_document[]" class="received-file-project" value="4">
            <input type="hidden" name="source_language" value="Spanish"><input type="hidden" name="target_language" value="Hindi">
            <input type="hidden" name="title" value="test_new_file">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_group_name" value="Article Rewrite_test3"></td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>file name</td>
        <td> file language</td>
        <td class="checkboxes">
            <input type="checkbox" name="finance_received_document[]" class="received-file-project" value="5">
            <input type="hidden" name="source_language" value="Norway"><input type="hidden" name="target_language" value="German">
            <input type="hidden" name="title" value="test_new_file">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_group_name" value="Article Rewrite"></td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <button class="btn btn-primary approve-price pull-right">Approve Price</button>
    </tr>               
</table>
```

Here you can see inside a table there are multiple rows with checkboxes. At table bottom there is one button named Approve Price. So I want to get the values of those rows which has been checked when user will click on approve price.

So I made my jquery like this

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.approve-price', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ids = [];
    var Selected = $(this).parents('table').find('td.checkboxes');
    var id = Selected.find(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
        ids[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    if( ids.length > 0 ) {
        console.log(ids);
        //ajax goes here for save data to the database
    }
    else {
        alert('Please select at least one checkbox');
    }
})
```

;

Here I am getting the values of id which has been checked. But how to get those hiden values
in which row the checkbox has been clicked. I want a solid method by which I can 
send those values in ordered way so that I can save them to the database using ajax. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just send the whole form as is ?

Comment: @Brewal I want the values of that row which has been checked. Not all the values of form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.siblings()`

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.approve-price', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ids = [];
    var Selected = $(this).parents('table').find('td.checkboxes');
    var id = Selected.find(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
        var obj = {};
        $(this).siblings().each(function(j){
            obj[$(this).attr("name")]=$(this).val();
        });
        obj["id"]=$(this).val();
        ids[i] = obj;
    });
    if( ids.length > 0 ) {
        console.log(ids);
        //ajax goes here for save data to the database
        $.ajax({
             //...
             data : JSON.stringify(ids)
        })
    }
    else {
        alert('Please select at least one checkbox');
    }
});
```

eg. selecting the 2 first checkboxes, generates this array

```
[
    {id:"1",
     product_group_name: "Article Rewrite_Test",
     source_language: "English",
     target_language: "German",
     title: "test_file"
    },
    {id: "4",
     product_group_name: "Article Rewrite_test3",
     source_language: "Spanish",
     target_language: "Hindi",
     title: "test_new_file"
    }
]
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/po67vznL/1/)

Comment: How to get the value in ajax? Lets say I want to get the value of id in ajax. So how I can get that?

Comment: do you mean get the values in server side? most languages have ways to parse a json string.

Answer (score 0):

How about you try this, so in the Back End server you can easily retrieve the values,

```
var ids = [];
var Selected = $(this).parents('table').find('td.checkboxes');
var that;
var id = Selected.find(':checkbox').each(function(i) {
    that = $(this);
    if(that.is(':checked'))
        ids.push( {id:i,value:that.val()} );
});
if( ids.length > 0 ) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ids));
    //ajax goes here for save data to the database
    $.ajax({
        url : <url>
        data : JSON.stringify(ids)
        ...
    })
}
```

Comment: it is showing the value like [{"id":0,"value":"1"}]. So for all other values for that row should I have to change something?

Comment: Ok just tell me one thing do you need all the checked or all the checked and unchecked ??

Comment: check out the last edit. I guess you wanted the index, Here the index starts at 0 , if you want from one you can push `(i+1)` as index. If you want the unchecked ones to go to the server as well you need to remove `if(that.is(':checked'))` and based on this check you can populate the `that.val()`